# .htaccess redirect after replace a word

Tags: .htaccess

I need to use .htaccess file to replace a world in URL

something like this:

example URL: www.hotourism.com/banknotes/banknotes/asia/vietnam/

redirect to: www.hotourism.com/countries-banknotes/banknotes/asia/vietnam/

how can I use mod_rewrite to redirect every URL containt "/banknotes/banknotes/" to the same URL after replacing that word?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
RewriteRule /countries-(.*) $1
```